# Group Concatenate Strings (Rows) in BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am working with Google BigQuery & I have a query that looks like the following:

```
 SELECT
        prod.abc
        uniqueid,
        variable2,
        cust.variable1,
        purch.variable2,
        from mydata.order
        left join
        UNNEST(purchases) as purch,
        UNNEST(codes_abs) as cod, UNNEST(cod.try_products) as prod
```

When I do this, this results in a table that looks like this:

```
    |prod.abc| uniqueid | variable2 | ...|
    |APP123  | customer1| value     | ...|
    |BLU155  | customer1| value     | ...|
    |TRI134  | customer1| value     | ...|
    |LO123   | customer2| value     | ...|
    |ZU9274  | customer2| value     | ...|
    |TO134   | customer3| value     | ...|
```

What I would like to do is to concatenate values in column "prod.abc", group them by "uniqueid" and separate them by ",". I found numerous solutions online, however, since I have unnested other variables in my query, none of the solutions I found seem to work in my case. The values do not need to be ordered in any way. Basically, what I would like to end up with is:

```
    |prod.abc                  | uniqueid | variable2 | ...|
    |APP123, BLU155, TRI134    | customer1| value     | ...|
    |LO123, ZU9274             | customer2| value     | ...|
    |TO134                     | customer3| value     | ...|
```

It would also be okay to get a table like this where duplicates are kept, as I could remove them later on:

```
|prod.abc                  | uniqueid | variable2 | ...|
|APP123, BLU155, TRI134    | customer1| value     | ...|
|APP123, BLU155, TRI134    | customer1| value     | ...|
|APP123, BLU155, TRI134    | customer1| value     | ...|
|LO123, ZU9274             | customer2| value     | ...|
|LO123, ZU9274             | customer2| value     | ...|
|TO134                     | customer3| value     | ...|
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do each unnest separately:
Does aggregation work?

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(item.abc, ',')
       uniqueid, variable2, cust.variable1, purch.variable2
FROM mydata.order LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(purchases) as purch
     ON true LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(codes_abs) as cod
     ON true LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(cod.try_items) as item
     ON true
GROUP BY uniqueid, variable2, cust.variable1, purch.variable2;
```

Comment: Worked very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(prod.abc, ', ') AS abc
  uniqueid,
  variable2,
  cust.variable1,
  purch.variable2,
FROM mydata.order
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(purchases) AS purch
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(codes_abs) AS cod
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(cod.try_products) AS prod
GROUP BY uniqueid,
  variable2,
  cust.variable1,
  purch.variable2
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot, worked euqally well as Gordons answer. I gave you an updovte, but had to accepts Gordons answer, because he was first. Thanks a lot, though!